# Is there any HTML 5 construct that is ONLY supported in the XML serialization?

Tags: css, html, dom, xhtml, specifications

Does there exist any "thing"(element, DOM manipulation, styling, nesting of elements, attributes, anything of that sort...) one can do in XHTML 5, that one CANNOT do in HTML 5? I remember reading on the web about one such case, but I cannot recall where it is I saw it.

This is apart from the use of content from external namespaces such as SVG and MathML (which is supported in HTML as well).

For reference, the number of answers to the converse question "what can you do in HTML 5 that you can't in XHTML 5?" are very large, given the strictness of XHTML. Hence I'm looking for answers to this question.

Comment: you can assume that all tag attributes in xhtml have a value. html/html5 allow bare `<foo bar>` attributes, where xhtml requires `<foo bar="bar">`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for example entity declarations and references to entities so defined. They are part of XML, so they must be supported when using XML serialization, as it is required to follow generic XML rules. Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html [
<!ENTITY foo "Hello world">
]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
&foo;
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

- XHTML, being XML supports xml-stylesheet declarations. Not just CSS but also XSLT. Which can transform the document tree before presentation
  XSLT also supports inclusions via `document("foo.xml")`, which can be used as an XInclude surrogate since no browser supports the latter right now.
- XML parsers validate well-formedness
- XHTML supports namespaces, allowing other XML content (not just SVG and MathML) to be embedded
- CDATA sections
- `.innerHTML`, `.insertAdjacentHTML()` and `.createContextualFragment()` validate well-formedness

The topic is quite interesting in general. E.g. an XHTML5 parser is not quite the same as a pure XML parser, as the HTML5 spec mandates a few willful violations of the XML parser, e.g. to support the [`<template>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#templateTagXML).

There also are a handful of states in which you can have a valid DOM that will throw an error if you try to export it through the [XHTML fragment serialization algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#serializing-xhtml-fragments).
And the [HTML Fragment serialization algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#serializing-html-fragments) may emit a string which will result in a different DOM when parsed again by a HTML parser.

So basically all three of the following are not fully isomorphic to one another, in any combination:

- the XHTML5 serialization
- the (X)HTML5 DOM
- the HTML5 serialization.

Answer (score 1):

In XHTML, you can use self-closing syntax (`/>`) on non-void elements:

```
<script src="js.js" />
```

And void elements can have stray end tags:

```
<input></input>
```

Comment: You can, but don't use it just because you can. This is STRONGLY discouraged in XHTML!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find what I was remembering vaguely in this [unofficial Q&A by hsivonen](https://hsivonen.fi/xhtml2-html5-q-and-a/). I'm still looking for other such "features".

> [...] In this case, you must avoid constructs that aren’t supported in text/html (e.g. div as a child of p).

Searching about more, I found [this page](http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/3089962.htm) (second post from top) :

> but basically a p can never enclose a div in HTML (or XHTML served with the mime type text/html). If you are serving XHTML with an XML mime type, you can do this in theory, but the result would not be valid XHTML.

saying that the HTML parser simply doesn't allow the possibility, while the XHTML parser, which doesn't need to second-guess the code, accepts it but it's still invalid.

I decided to test it out : took an `application/xhtml+xml` [page](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/), tried to add a `div` inside a `p` using Chrome dev tools "Edit as HTML" function. It worked. I copied the source, made the same change and tested it in [validator.nu](http://validator.nu/). It marked it as invalid, to my slight disappointment.

Trying to add a div in a `text/html` page in the same manner was impossible. As soon as I exited the "Edit as HTML" mode, it simply moved the `div` after the `p`.

Comment: For the p/div in the pure XML DOM case (without a hybrid XML/HTML5 DOM implementation) it would depend on the browser getting a DTD that imposes such constraints. So I guess we have to distinguish further between parsers and subtypes of DOM implementations.

Comment: @the8472 yes, but the canonical definition of XHTML would be the w3c spec, which outlaws p/div . is it impossible to enforce it using DTD? I doubt it. Of course, XHTML 5 has no officially defined DTD (seems very vindictive against XML on the part of the standards writers to me)

Comment: There are some restrictions in the HTML5 element definitions which cannot be implemented with DTDs. The p/div case is *not* one of them. But if you present it as XML without a DTD then a parser adhering to the XML spec is free to accept them. A parser and/or DOM implementation that follows the mandates of the HTML5 spec (which makes stipulations for XML too) then it would be different. We basically have several different specs here that say different things.

Comment: There are more useful constructs possible in an XML serialization of HTML than `<div>` in `<p>`, for example nested `<form>`s, which work fine and the HTML5 spec fully defines their behaviour, but like `<div>` in `<p>` they are intentionally defined as invalid in XHTML5.

Comment: @Alohci please add it as an answer. This is the kind of thing I'm looking for.